# animate to the value in the css/class

Tags: jquery

```
//startling class of object
.c1 { width: 100px; }

//object gets animated
$(".c1").animate({width: 200},500);

//I wanna animate the object back to the initial width
//without animate I would do
$(".c1").css("width", "");
//to clear the inline style
```

Is it somehow possible to do this without a work around?

---

My work around would be to clear the inlinestyle, read the width, set inlinestyle again and animate. Like this:

```
$this = $(".c1");
var tempwidth=$this.width();
$this.css("width", "");
var targetwidth=$this.width();
$this.css("width", tempwidth);
$this.animate({width: targetwidth},1000);
```

Comment: What event are you running this code under? You could potentially do this very simply using CSS `transform` depending on the browser support you want.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan good point. with css transform it would be easy. But it will not be so easy to rewrite all the code, cause I use the callback .done() and also the queues. So I would have to write some logic to handle the queues bymyself. Would be nice to have a solution with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var realwidth = parseInt($('.c').width());

    $('.c').animate({width: 200},1000);
     $('.c').click(function(){
        $(this).animate({width: realwidth},1000);
     });
});
```

[**DEMO with click**](http://jsfiddle.net/ya95p4L8/)
animate onload and click the div to animate back

---

and if you don want a click event just use this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var realwidth = parseInt($('.c').width());
    $('.c').animate({width: 200},1000).animate({width: realwidth},1000);
});
```

[**DEMO without click**](http://jsfiddle.net/ya95p4L8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by storing the initial css value to element data storage (by using the jQuery [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method ). Later, for example, compare the current value with the initial value to toggle the element, [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2yz9mhpm/).

```
// set the initial value
$( '.c1' ).each( function() {
    $(this).data( 'width', $(this).width() );
});

// animate element
$(".c1").animate( { width: 200 }, 500 );

// animate element back to initial value
var width = $( ".c1" ).data( 'width' );
$( ".c1" ).animate( { width: width }, 500 );
```